# In the context of ordered statistics, each of Y(1),Y(2),...,Y(n) a single observation or distributions that are I.I.D?

Tags: statistics

In statistics one aspect of the I.I.D. concept that bothers is when I think about it in the context of ordered statistics. As most of you already know, $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,...,Y_n$ are I.I.D. when the parameters are the same.

Now, here are two things I'm confused about.

1. In the context of ordered statistics, each of $Y_{(1)},Y_{(2)},...,Y_{(n)}$ a single observation or distributions that are I.I.D?
2. If they are distributions, how in the world is it possible to order distributions from the least to greatest??

Comment: Suppose $Y_i\sim U(0,1)$, $n=2$. Then $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(2)})$ is uniformly distributed in the triangle which forms a half of the unit square.

Comment: A.S. could you elaborate on the 'triangle' you are referring to?

Comment: Draw a unit square and triangle with vertices at $(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have $Y_1,Y_2, \dotsc, Y_n$ and each are independent and follow some distribution $G$, then you could consider each $Y_i$ as a realization, or sample, taken from $G$. 
If you then order, then each $Y_{(i)}$ follows a new distribution.

For example, say we have $Y_1, \dotsc, Y_n$, where each one is independent and  follows a $\text{unif}(0,1)$. Then, it should be clear, that each $Y_i\sim \text{unif}(0,1)$ (nothing changed). Once we order then, however, recall that for example, the first ordered statistic $Y_{(1)}\sim \text{Beta}(1,n)$ ([Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)). It is still an observation, but $Y_{(1)}$ **follows** a *different* distribution from $Y_1$. And in general, $Y_i\sim\text{unif}(0,1)$, **but**
$$Y_{(i)}\sim \text{Beta}(i, n+1 -i).$$

---

You don't order the distributions, you order the $Y_i$s.

For example, the distribution of $Y_{(1)}$ goes as follows
$$P(Y_{(1)}\leq z) = 1-P(Y_{(1)}>z) =1- (1-z)^n.$$
Then the pdf is $n(1-z)^{n-1}$. Notice that the interpretation is that
there is $\binom{n}{1}$ options for the smallest. Then the rest $\binom{n-1}{n-1} = 1$ have to fall in the interval $(1-z)$, hence $n(1-z)^{n-1}$.

---

Let $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ iid exponential distributions with mean $1/\lambda$. Then, to find distribution of the minimum $M:=Y_{(1)}$, we must consider
$$P(M\in dm)$$
There are $3$ choices, for the minimum

1. $Y_1$, or
2. $Y_2$ or
3. $Y_3$.

Once we have chosen the smallest, then there is only one way to choose the other two larger ones. So it must be the case that
$$P(M\in dm) = \binom{3}{1}f_Y(m)\binom{2}{2}(1-F_Y(m))^2 =3\lambda e^{-\lambda m}(e^{-\lambda m})^2 = 3\lambda e^{-3\lambda m}$$ 
Notice that the minimum $M$ (or $Y_{(1)}$) follows an exponential distribution with mean $\frac{1}{3\lambda}$.

Comment: Are Yi itself a distribution or individual observation?

Comment: The reason for my confusion is that my professor used ordered statistics of exponential distribution to illustrate a flashlight scenario in which there are 3 flash lights (n =3) and you are concerned with the flashlight that will last the longest which is Y(3). Doesn't that make y(1),y(2),and y(3) just mere observations that are ordered based on least to greatest?

Comment: @DanielLee Yes, I believe you can say that. However, the point is to notice that, in  your example, each $Y_i$ follows the **same** exponential distribution. But, $Y_{(i)}$ does **not** follow the same exponential distribution.

Comment: "Yi follows the same exponential distribution. But, Y(i) does not follow the same exponential distribution." That's what I can't seem to wrap my head around. If Y(i) is mere ordered version of Yi and Yi's are IID then shouldn't that apply to Y(i) as well?

Comment: And also. Do you agree with me that Y(i)'s are distributions? If that's the case, how is it possible for me to order them?

Comment: @DanielLee 1. No, I just gave you an example above that shows that $Y_i$ does not follow the same distribution as $Y_{(i)}$ 2. Random variables are not distributions; we say that they **follows** a certain distribution. You might also here that a random variable _has_ a certain distribution. For future, reference, provide all relevant details in your question. I will revise my answer to use your example.

Comment: @DanielLee I changed my answer. This is how you order them and notice that $Y_1$ does not _follow_ the same distribution as $Y_{(1)}$.

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Much appreciated :)

Comment: @DanielLee Great! I'm glad I could help. If you find an answer correct or most useful, please consider giving it a [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Toss two coins.  Let $Y_i=1$ if the i-th coin is a head and $Y_i=0$ if it is a tail.

Then we have $\{Y_1, Y_2\}$, which are two independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables.

So what does the distribution of $\{Y_{(1)}, Y_{(2)}\}$ look like?

$$\begin{array}{l|llll:l} ~ & TT & HT & TH & HH
\\ \hline Y_1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\\ Y_2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\\ \hdashline Y_{(1)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \min\{Y_1, Y_2\}
\\ Y_{(2)} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \max\{Y_1, Y_2\}
\end{array}$$

Clearly they are is not identical nor independent.   (If you know that the largest is $0$ then the smallest is certainly also $0$.)