# Why is the mean of the minimum of $100$ exponentially distributed random variables equal to $\beta$ divided by $n$?

Tags: statistics

Here's a question about order statistics, I can't seem to understand.

> Suppose a battery lasts $1,000$ hours. If I have $100$ batteries, why is it that the mean that the first battery will go out will be $10$ hours?

I understand how $10$ hours was derived. It's $\beta$ divided by $n$. But, $10$ hours doesn't seem to make any sense. No matter what order, shouldn't the mean be $1,000$?

Comment: Is there an exponential distribution or something similar in the question? Perhaps some batteries dies before others due to the distribution and *first* means *earliest to go out*

Comment: It is an exponential distribution.

Comment: You should be careful when referring the the parameter since everyone does not follow the same convention. $\beta$ can refer to the rate or scale.

Comment: Take a large bunch of people. The length of life of the first person to die is (probably) going to be substantially less than average.

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of a battery follows an exponential distribution with mean $1000$.

It is well known that the minimum of $n$ iid exponential random variables follows an exponential distribution with mean $1000/n$. In fact, I explained this to you [in the case that $n=3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1639911).
Hence, the expected lifetime of the first to die is
$$\frac{1000}{100} = 10$$

It should not be $1000$ since the minimum lifetime of $n$ batteries does not follow the same distribution as the lifetime of any one particular battery,
$$\min\{X_1,\dotsc,X_n\} \overset{d}{\neq} X_i.$$